# Excel keeps crashing with Worksheet_selectionChange

Tags: vba, excel

I am running two VBA formulas.

The first hides all cells with empty information the first column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

     Dim c As Range
     On Error Resume Next

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     For Each c In Range("A3:A49")
        If c.Value = vbNullString Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c

    For Each c In Range("A3:A47")
        If c.Value <> vbNullString Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The second Formula strings data together and placeses this information in the next cell that is empty (aka the first hidden cell) when the button is clicked.

```
Option Explicit

    Dim iwsh As Worksheet
    Dim owsh As Worksheet
    Dim output As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Sub Copy()

    Set iwsh = Worksheets("Budget")
    Set owsh = Worksheets("Release Burnup")

    i = 3

    While owsh.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

    i = i + 1

    Wend

    output = "R" & iwsh.Cells(13, 2).Value & "-S" & iwsh.Cells(14, 2).Value

    owsh.Cells(i, 1) = output

    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

End Sub
```

Previously, this has been causing no problem... Something has happened that is causing the workbook to crash anytime I try to delete information out of one of the cells with the new data.

PS: This is the list of my other formulas. maybe there is something in these that is interacting with the formentioned code?

```
Private Sub NewMemberBut_Click()

    'causes userform to appear
    NewMember.Show

    'reformats button because button kept changing size and font
    NewMemberBut.AutoSize = False
    NewMemberBut.AutoSize = True
    NewMemberBut.Height = 40.25
    NewMemberBut.Left = 303.75
    NewMemberBut.Width = 150

End Sub

'Similar code to the problematic code in question, but this one works fine
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In Range("A3:A35,A41:A80")
        If c.Value = vbNullString Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c

    For Each c In Range("A3:A35,A41:A80")
        If c.Value <> vbNullString Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


'Code for UserForm

Option Explicit

    Dim mName As String
    Dim cName As String
    Dim mRole As String
    Dim cRole As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Perc As Integer
    Dim Vac As Integer
    Dim Prj As Worksheet
    Dim Bud As Worksheet

Private Sub NewMember_Initialize()

    txtName.Value = ""

    cboRoleList.Clear

    Scrum.Value = False

    txtPercent.Value = ""

    txtVacation.Value = ""

    txtName.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub AddMember_Click()

    If Me.txtName.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a Member name.", vbExclamation, "New Member"
        Me.txtName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.cboRoleList = "Other" And Me.txtCustomRole = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please provide a role name.", vbExclamation, "Other Role"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.cboRoleList.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a Role.", vbExclamation, "Member Role"
        Me.cboRoleList.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.cboRoleList <> "Other" And Me.txtPercent = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a valid percentage to be applied to this sprint.", vbExclamation, "Sprint Percent"
        Me.txtPercent.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtPercent.Value > 100 And Me.txtPercent <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a valid percentage to be applied to this sprint.", vbExclamation, "Sprint Percent"
        Me.txtPercent.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.txtVacation.Value = "" Then
        Me.txtVacation.Value = 0
    End If

    Dim i As Long

    Set Prj = Worksheets("Project Team")
    Set Bud = Worksheets("Budget")

    Prj.Activate

    i = 5
    x = 1
    If Me.cboRoleList.Value = "Other" Then
        i = 46
    End If


    While Prj.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    If cboRoleList = "Other" Then
        Cells(i, x).Value = txtCustomRole.Value
    End If

    If cboRoleList <> "Other" Then
        Cells(i, x).Value = cboRoleList.Value
    End If
    x = x + 1

    Cells(i, x).Value = txtName.Value
    x = x + 1

    If Me.cboRoleList.Value <> "Other" Then
        Cells(i, x).Value = txtPercent.Value
    End If

    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub CloseBut_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: The answer to this is "what changed", Worked before, stopped working so What changed?  Isolate that change and you should be able to resolve this.

Comment: `c.EntireRow.Hidden = cbool(c.Value = vbNullString)`once and skip the second loop maybe?

Comment: Does Excel crash if you manually delete the data?  Is it always the same row/column/cell?

Comment: Should `Worksheet_SelectionChange` be `Worksheet_Change`? Do you really want to run that every time you *select* a cell or just when something in A3:A49 changes?

Comment: That is a fantastic point regarding the selection change. I am still relatively new and self taught. So much of my code, I am sure is very sloppy. 


Also, I did change Worksheet_SelectionChange to Worksheet_Change and that seems to have fixed it.
As far as "What changed?" The code that is causing the crash is the first code I put in. everything else I have added little by little since that point. I had not bothered checking the functionality of it until now because I had assumed that everything would work fine as they don't interact with eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the event driven Worksheet_SelectionChange to Worksheet_Change and isolate further by only processing when something changes in A3:A49.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A49")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A49"))
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(c.Value = vbNullString)
        Next c
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Caveat:** A Worksheet_Change is not triggered on the change in a cell from the cell's formula. Only by typing, deleting or dragging a cell's contents. Adding or removing a formula will trigger it but not when a formula's result changes from another value somewhere in the workbook changing. This should not affect you as no formula can return vbNullString but it is worth mentioning for others.